# Converting Partial String dates to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a free text column containing dates provided by my client. The column will have values something like the below.

> 2014-02
>
> 21-12-2013
>
> 2014-06-28
>
> 9/10/2014
>
> 2009

It may contain partial dates, different date format. I need to convert these values to datetime.

I tried many ways to convert the data and some are below.

I tried to find the length and check whether is date using the below code

```
CASE
        WHEN ISDATE(@stringDate) = 1 THEN CAST(@stringDate AS DATETIME)
        WHEN LEN(@stringDate) = 4 THEN CAST(('01-01' + @stringDate) AS DATETIME)
        WHEN LEN(@stringDate) = 7 THEN CAST((@stringDate + '-01') AS DATETIME)
    END
```

This worked fine however when the data changes its format the above code will not work.

Is there any way to create a function that will convert the partial dates to datetime field?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the data changes its format the above code will not work"? So your solution work or no? In what cases It fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function as below to solve my requirement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DateConvert] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @inDate varchar(15)
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OutDate datetime

SET @OutDate = (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN ISDATE(@inDate) = 0 AND
                LEN(@inDate) > 8 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIME, @inDate, 103), 121)
            WHEN ISDATE(@inDate) = 0 AND
                LEN(@inDate) = 4 THEN CAST('01-01-' + @inDate AS DATETIME)
            WHEN ISDATE(@inDate) = 0 AND
                LEN(@inDate) = 7 AND
                @inDate LIKE '%-%' THEN CAST(@inDate + '-01' AS DATETIME)
            WHEN ISDATE(@inDate) = 0 AND
                LEN(@inDate) = 7 AND
                @inDate LIKE '%/%' THEN CAST(@inDate + '/01' AS DATETIME)
            ELSE CAST(@inDate AS DATETIME)
        END)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @OutDate
END
```

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of solution to satisfy the requirement as you wrote it but that's because the question is flawed.

the right question is: does exists a **dependable** way to create a function that will convert the partial dates to datetime field?

the answer is **no, such a function does not exists**.

that's because there is no dependable way to tell if `11-05-2009` is `2009-05-11` or `2009-11-05` if you have no clue of the format of the initial string.

even the solution you use:

```
WHEN ISDATE(@stringDate) = 1 THEN CAST(@stringDate AS DATETIME)
```

may produce the wrong result because the string itself is a date but the value 'guessed' by the system depends on various settings and it is not necessarily the same value that the user input.

here is a quick example:

```
DECLARE @stringDate AS VARCHAR(10) = '10/05/2009';
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT CAST(@stringDate AS DATETIME); --2009-10-05 00:00:00.000
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT CAST(@stringDate AS DATETIME); --2009-05-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. As mentioned by you, I need to modify my question as not a generic function.

Comment: my point is still valid because it is about 'dependable' and not about 'generic'. please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I suppose when there is better build-in function [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) then one shouldn't have to write own solution.

> Examples http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/